# Getting a IllegalStateException when trying to use Toast.hide on background thread

Tags: java, android

```
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed.
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.MessageQueue.removeSyncBarrier(MessageQueue.java:619)
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.unscheduleTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1621)
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:4142)
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:7450)
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:7410)
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:520)
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:451)
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:210)
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleHide(Toast.java:536)
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.handleMessage(Toast.java:407)
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
01-28 13:58:33.180 29745 12204 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Got no clue how to debug this. I have a Intent service that launches this Toast.hide()

Comment: Don't show Toasts on a background thread. Use the main thread.

Comment: On which Android version u r testing it?

Comment: @nicolas thanks for replying. the intent service (which launch the toast) are in background thread. Should I make a callback to make the toast showing in the main thread?

Comment: See @Zain link, this is the way to go.